# What is second level cache in hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, second-level-cache

What is second level cache in hibernate ?

Answer (score 40):

Hibernate comes with three different caches: first level, second level and query cache.

The *first level cache* is the Hibernate Session and is used to track the state of entities during the current Session (or unit of work). This is a transaction-level cache.

The *second level cache* shares entity state across various Session. This is a SessionFactory-level cache.

The *query cache* is used to cache queries (and their parameters) and their results.

#### Recommended readings

- [The Second Level Cache](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-cache) in the documentation
- [Hibernate: Truly Understanding the Second-Level and Query Caches](https://web.archive.org/web/20190719063218/https://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t48846.html)
- [Understanding Caching in Hibernate – Part One : The Session Cache](https://www.dynatrace.com/news/blog/)
- [Hibernate Caches](https://acupof.blogspot.com/2008/01/background-hibernate-comes-with-three.html)