# Caching large data sets with hibernate/jpa/memcache?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, redis, memcached

I'm new to open source stacks and have been playing with hibernate/jpa/jdbc and memcache.  I have a large data set per jdbc query and possibly will have a number these large data sets where I eventually bind to a chart.

However, I'm very focused on performance instead of hitting the database per page load to display it on my web page chart.

Are there some examples of how (memcache, redis, local or distributed) and where to cache this data (jSON or raw result data) to load in memory? Also I need to figure out how to refresh the cache unless it's a time based eviction marking algorithm (i.e. 30min expires so grab new data from data base query instead of using cache or perhaps an automated feed of data into the cache every xhrs/min/etc).?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is typical problem and solution not straight forward. There are many factor which determine your design. Here is what we did sometime ago

- Since our queries to extract data were a bit **complex** (*took around a min to execute*) and **large dataset**, we populated the memcache from a batch which used to pull data from database every 1 hour and push it to the memcached.  By keeping the expiry cache larger than the batch interval, we made sure that where will always be data in cache.
- There was another used case for **dynamic caching**, wherein on receiving the request for data, we checked first the memcached and if data not found, query the database, fetch the data, push it to memcached and return the results. But I would advise for this approach only when your database queries are **simple and fast** enough not to cause the poor overall response.
- You can also used Hibernat's [second level cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7058843/when-and-how-to-use-hibernate-second-level-cache). It depends on your database schema, queries etc. to use this feature efficiently.

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate has built-in support for 2nd level caching. Take a look at EhCache for example.

Also see: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-cache