# Hibernate in memory data + database

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, tomcat, spring-boot

I have an application which already written in Hibernate and is mapped to hiberante database annotations (and in the background I am using Postgres as DB).
I was wondering if there is a way to keep the database as is, but to add another level of "database" which holds everything In-Memory in java object?

What I mean is,
1) keep Postgres update when there is update/delete/create and only return after it is really commited.

2) when some DB Read queries executed, I want to be able to return the answer using my **java** object **And avoid calling the database for those Read operations**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When and how to use hibernate second level cache?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7058843/when-and-how-to-use-hibernate-second-level-cache) it's called a second level cache and this thread should answer all your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hibernate has an awesome feature built in called a second level cache.  This will allow you to "plugin" a caching system like ehcache to offload a lot of the database read load.  Ehcache can either be used standalone or in a distributed manor.  Ehcache on its own is a very powerful tool that you can also leverage in front of webservice calls and other lookups as well.  I will post a few decent reading links for you.

http://howtodoinjava.com/hibernate/hibernate-ehcache-configuration-tutorial/

http://www.mkyong.com/ehcache/ehcache-hello-world-example/

You can also consider using spring with ehcache for a more declarative caching style if you want to use it standalone

http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-caching-and-ehcache-example/