# How to use Redis as L2 cache on Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, caching, redis

I have a spring boot application and need to setup Redis as l2 cache on hibernate.

My prop file looks like:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.cache.region.factory_class = package.CustomRegionFactory
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.cache.redisson.fallback=false
```

I created a custom region factory because I don't want to use json or yaml files. (right now, the parameters are hardcoded).
CustomRegionFactory class looks like:

```
public class CustomRegionFactory extends RedissonRegionFactory {

    @Override
    public RedissonClient createRedissonClient(Properties properties) {     
        Config config = new Config();
        config.useSingleServer().setAddress("redis://127.0.0.1:6379").setRetryInterval(1500)
                .setRetryAttempts(3).setConnectTimeout(10000)
                .setClientName("client1");

        return Redisson.create(config);
    }
}
```

Using redis-cli I found out that all my entities annotated with `@Cacheable` are listed when using the command `keys *`. Until here I thought everything worked fine, but using the postgres logging resources I found out that the queries are hitting the database.

Does somebody have any tips to make it works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that using @Cacheable from hibernate will solve everything.

Answer (score 0):

You should use .setCachable(true) to make queries to be cached on hibernate level.
See [this](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core.old/reference/en/html/performance-querycache.html) documentaion.

Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7058843/when-and-how-to-use-hibernate-second-level-cache) question regarding second level cache on hibernate